# Laravel whereNotIn plus whereIn doesn't equal total count

Tags: php, laravel

How is it possible that `whereNotIn()` plus `whereIn()` doesn't equal total count?

Running this:

```
$updatedBreeds = [
    86,
    113,
    // etc ....
];

DB::enableQueryLog();

dump(Breed::count());
dump(Breed::whereIn('id', $updatedBreeds)->count());
dump(Breed::whereNotIn('id', $updatedBreeds)->count());

dd(DB::getQueryLog());
```

Returns this:

> 159
>   39
>   0

Am I missing something here? The `whereNotIn()` call should return 120 results.

Comment: Cache? Redis or something else?

Comment: Can you show the sql for the queries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, one of the values in the array was `null`. Which strangely enough led to this behavior.

Here is a dump on `$updatedBreeds`:

```
[
  0 => 86
  1 => 113
- 2 => null // When I removed this value, the whereNotIn() worked
  2 => 44
  3 => 8
  4 => 54
  5 => 54
  // ...
]
```